# Filtering Pandas Series of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got a Pandas Series with arrays in it, looks like this:

```py
In [80]: set.tail(7)
Out[80]: 
block_number
942                                                [b'??']
943                                                [b'??']
944                                      [b'??', b'\xff?']
945                                                [b'??']
65280                                        [b'\xff\xff']
65281                                        [b'\xff\xff']
65535    [b'\xff\xff', b'\x01\xa0', b'\x81\xa0', b'\x01...
Name: block_header, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to filter out those rows (block_number values) that have `b'\x3f3f'` in the array AND it must be the only value in the array.

I got this series as a result of a groupby from a df, something like this:

```py
set = frame[['block_number', 'block_header']]
        .groupby(['block_number'])['block_header'].agg('unique')
```

I'm struggling to use .where() w/ lambda on this Series, I guess this isn't trivial enough for first time Pandas use.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with condtions - check by `in` value in `array` and [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for get length of `array`:

```
s = frame[['block_number', 'block_header']]
          .groupby(['block_number'])['block_header'].agg('unique')

a = b'\x3f3f'
mask = (s.apply(lambda x: a in x)) & (s.str.len() == 1)
out = s[~mask]
```

Comment: Black magic, works like a charm. Back to the docs to understand how that works :-)

Comment: All the docs say ".str can be used to access the values of the series as strings and apply several methods to it" - in this case it seems to work (it returns len() of the array) - but I don't understand why, i'd expect it'd get casted to string or something weird. any idea how this works exactly?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit cofused. But  list or array of some values in column has same bahavious as string for lengths.

Comment: Check it `print (len('aaaa'))` and `print (len([1,2,3,4]))`